# HuBL: How to check what lists a contact is part of by contact ID?

Tags: twig, hubspot, hubl

I'm trying to show specific content if a user is part of a list in HubSpot.

**Psuedo**:

`If contact_id is part_of_this_list then do this`

The contact ID at the moment is being obtained from the query string. I'm trying to check if the user is part of said list, but it's not working.

**Approach**:

```
{% set id_querystring = request.query_dict.id %}
{% set registration_list_id = "6136" %} <!-- id of the list I'm checking -->

{% if id_querystring in registration_list_id %}
 contact is part of list
{% else %}
 contact is not part of list
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Try using [`dump()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) on `request.query_dict.id` so we have an idea of that variable structure and post it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

i use this code:

```
{% set list_variable = request_contact.list_memberships|pprint %}
{% if "id of the list you are checking" in list_variable %} ← without the quotes

yes, you are in the list

{%else%}

No, you are not in the list

{%endif%}
```